# Convert Unix timestamp to a readable date in Perl

Tags: perl, timestamp

I have some Unix timestamps (for example, 1357810480, so they're mainly in the past). How can I transform them into a readable date-format using Perl?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) for that.

```
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime($unix_timestamp);
```

Comment: Yeah, that would put the array in `$time`.  After that the hour is in `$time[2]` for example.

Comment: thanks, but i'd like to store the  formatted date directly in a single variable. do you see any possibility for this? my current solution seems to save the current date, no matter how old the given timestamp is

Comment: One way is `$formatted_time = scalar(localtime($unix_timestamp))`, or using [`Date::Format`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Format.pm), `$formatted_time = time2str("%D", $unix_timestamp);`

Comment: @hurley, it returns data for the given timestamp, not the "current date".

Answer (score 38):

Quick shell one-liner:

```
perl -le 'print scalar localtime 1357810480;'
Thu Jan 10 10:34:40 2013
```

Or, if you happen to have the timestamps in a file, one per line:

```
perl -lne 'print scalar localtime $_;' <timestamps
```

Answer (score 22):

You could use

```
my ($S, $M, $H, $d, $m, $Y) = localtime($time);
$m += 1;
$Y += 1900;
my $dt = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $Y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S);
```

But it's a bit simpler with `strftime`:

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );
my $dt = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($time));
```

`localtime($time)` can be substituted with `gmtime($time)` if it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 21):

A perfect use for [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) (standard in Perl since 5.10).

```
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;

my $unix_timestamp = 1e9; # for example;

my $date = localtime($unix_timestamp)->strftime('%F %T'); # adjust format to taste

say $date; # 2001-09-09 02:46:40
```

Comment: `'%f %T'` does not work for me (maybe because of my locale), but `'%Y-%m-%d'` does work.

Comment: Time::Piece's strange and buggy handling of timezones has made me swear it off. It can be used for turning a timestamp into a string, but trying to extract a timestamp from a Time::Piece object gives unexpected and unreliable results. It alters the timestamp to match the machine's timezone, actually adding or subtracting the seconds from it, resulting in an inaccurate timestamp. When you later retrieve your timestamp, you will find it is x hours off.

Comment: felwithe probably used `Time::Piece->new(...)` instead of `localtime(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

Or, if you have a file with embedded timestamps, you can convert them in place with:

```
cat [file] | perl -pe 's/([\d]{10})/localtime $1/eg;'
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! I can just pipe my log file into that perl one-liner and BINGO instant date/times.

Answer (score 2):

I liked JDawg's answer but couldn't get it to work properly on a RHEL system I was working on. I was able to get this to work. Hopefully this will help someone. It displays the contents of a file with the converted timestamps in place.

`cat filename | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e'`

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer, you can also replace localtime with gmtime in order to get the UTC time.  I found this very useful in my Bash scripts:

UTC:

```
echo 1357810480  | perl -nE 'say scalar gmtime $_'
```

Local:

```
echo 1357810480  | perl -nE 'say scalar localtime $_'
```

You can replace `say` with `print` if you don't require a new line at the end of the output.

Comment: What answer do you refer to? Or do you mean *"answers"* (several)?